# Is there an alternate place to ask for story identification for non-sci-fi?

Tags: discussion, story-identification, site-rec

Unfortunately, this is likely an off-topic question, but one which is about said off-topicness. Occasionally, when browsing through [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) items, one comes upon a request for a story that is non-sci-fi with people suggesting going to the [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com) to ask. That section of the site was closed in 2012. So far, I've been resorting to TV Trope's YKTS board, but is there an SE location to ask such questions?

Comment: There is the Booksleuth Forum at [abe.com](http://www.abebooks.com/).

Comment: Try the [tipofmytongue](http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue) subreddit

Comment: Yahoo answers. Or Quora

Comment: @FuzzyBoots what was that about part of Literature being closed?

Comment: @Stormblessed: This isn't the first time Literature SE has been created. It kind of failed the first time due to lack of interest.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be a full answer since it's just one resource; but the subreddit /r/whatsthatbook is pretty good for books.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are actually quite a few sites that allow some type of identification question:

- [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com): [Literature ID questions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/5747) are on-topic. You can ask about more than books: comics, manga, graphic novels, short stories, and poems are on-topic. (To clarify, this site was launched in 2017, long after the old Literature site closed in 2012.)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/): [Game ID questions are on-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10198/153006) if a screenshot, audio file or other "artifact" of the game is included. Otherwise, they have this [short list of external sites](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7618/153006) which may help you find games.
- [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com): [Game ID questions](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/462) for [retro](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/462) games are on-topic.
- [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/): Questions asking for the identification of anime or manga [are now **off**-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2805) (but there is [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4697/41946) to help in your search). Questions about identifying characters, episodes, or similar from a known series are [on-topic](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4190), as are questions on identifying cosplay and merchandise when [there's a good reason to believe it's from an anime/manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4142). (But it looks like no more [music id](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4491/50617).)
- [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/): The tag [product-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-identification) is appropriate for most id questions, unless you're asking to identify something within a known game and then you want to use the [content-identification tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-identification). In any case, as long as you're asking for the identification of a tabletop RPG (not a video game), it's likely on topic.
- [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/): This site accepts [identification questions](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/195) for anything matching the title of the site, using the [identify-this-game tag](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game). For [identification of foreign Magic: The Gathering cards](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1185), there's a post with [guidance on how to find the answer yourself](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18820).

And it's also worth mentioning:

- Movies & TV: ID questions of any type are now [**off**-topic](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/70064). They do have a [list of external sites](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/70064) that could help though.
- [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/): After many years of lukewarmly supporting them,  [no ID questions](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733).

Answer (score 12):

For books?  <s>Nothing on Stack Exchange.</s> There is now a [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) which accepts (well-worded and detailed) identification requests.

<s>For movies?  There's [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com).</s>

<s>For TV?  There's [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com).</s>

<s>For anime?  There's [Anime&Manga.SE](http://anime.stackexchange.com).</s> - they have now [completely banned](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2806/28456) story-ID requests.

For video games?  Nothing on Stack Exchange. There's [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), but only in the very specific case when [you have an “artifact”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7617/how-best-to-ask-about-a-game-identification/7621#7621) (e.g. a screenshot).

Be sure to take the tour on each site to see the constraints they have on Story Identification questions, each of them has different expectations.

Comment: I know Arqade has unilaterally banned identification requests, for example.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Whoops, last time I looked, they allowed ones with pictures. :3

Comment: @SeanDuggan [A mod on Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9751/8763) says they allow ID questions, if they include 'an artifact', like a screenshot.

Comment: Huh. Their documentation doesn't indicate that. Good to know.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Yeah, it's baffling to me that their Tour is so definite, and so wrong.

Comment: Movies have unilaterally banned story-ID questions. I've taken the liberty of striking that through for OP

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. There isn't a place to ask such questions (yet).

There is a [Literature Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80865/literature) on Area 51 that would suit your needs, but it is still on the Definition stage.

You can always ask around our chat. Someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Is there a reason to think that Books SE would fare any better than (sadly) Literature SE did?

Comment: @DVK I really don't know, but it is the only place that I think would suit OP's needs

Comment: @DVK What happened to Literature SE? It's something sad about the internet community -- i.e. *us* -- that such a SE site cannot prosper, while Movies SE can :(

Answer (score 3):

[The English Wikipedia reference desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk) does take well-written identification questions, and can sometimes answer them.  [Here's an example question I asked, for which a user found the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Humanities/2011_July_7#Find_a_fiction_book:_pilot's_girlfriend_must_land_small_airplane_when_pilot_falls_unconscious) (*Talk Down* by Brian Lecomber (1978)).  Ask book identification questions [at the humanities desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Humanities), movie or TV series or video game identification questions [at the entertainment desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Entertainment).  Don't ask the same question at multiple desks.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Book Search' sub-forum of SFF Chronicles they accept occasional non genre book ID questions.
 Provided the same person doesn't keep banging non SF&F questions in there day after day after day and thus alienating dedicated SF&F fans.