# Forums for open-ended discussion?

Tags: discussion

I like the SE format, and I like the fact that it focuses on clearly defined questions and discourages open-ended discussion. However, sometimes I want to engage in open-ended discussion, like in the old days on Usenet. I qualify for membership in [SFWA](https://www.sfwa.org/), which has forums, but my impression of SFWA is that it's a dysfunctional organization, so I don't want to pay dues to join.

Can anyone recommend an online discussion board for SF?

Comment: You can always try [chat] here, usually someone on. Otherwise a work’s appropriate subreddit is likely one of the more popular places for this sort of thing.

Comment: [This is somewhat related](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/452/58193), think there might be a couple other meta posts on it too.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot [Here's another one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/31394), still tagged as FAQ, but it hasn't been updated for years. Maybe this new meta could be a chance for a new updated FAQ on alternative discussion forums, and we can close the older ones as duplicates?

Comment: @Randal'Thor probably a good idea, it was one of the suggestions I made in the Ways to improve post I believe.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Also there's the [SE identification post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4772/58193), not what the OP is after but somewhat relevant.

Answer (score 3):

---

[The official chatrooms here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) are always an option. The interface has a lot to be desired, and it isn't very active, but you can often find someone there to chat with, especially if it's about Stack Exchange.

---

[The site's blog has a Discord](https://thesffblog.com/chat/), but there's even less activity there than in chat. (For example, there were a total of *twelve* messages posted there in the past six months.)

---

[There's a Slack group](https://ibid-11962.github.io/slack-invites/) started by [the late KutuluMike](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13081/kutulumike-michael-edenfield-has-passed-away/) that has a number of this site's long-time users (ten of the top thirty rep users are on it).

It was created a few years ago to give a forum for more open discussion than Stack Exchange chat allows, and has been steadily continuing since, with a good 5-10 users active there on any given day, and I've found it a to be a great community.

Pretty much all topics of sci-fi are welcome to be discussed, both related to this website and not.

---

You can also just head to a subreddit like [/r/scifi](https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/). You won't find much overlap in the userbase, but you'll certainly find a lot of activity.